# How much bandwidth a 4096 × 2160 x 30 @ 60Hz display uses?

Tags: display

How much bandwidth a 4096 × 2160 x 30 @ 60Hz display uses?

From Wikipedia's DisplayPort page: "17.28 Gbit/s of effective video bandwidth, enough for four simultaneous 1080p60 displays (CEA-861 timings) or 2,560 × 1,600 × 30 bit @120 Hz (CVT-R timings)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets take the "2,560 × 1,600 × 30 bit @120 Hz" example.

```
2560x1600 pixels             (4096000 pixels)
each pixel with 30 bit data  (4096000 x30 bits)
transmitted 120 times per second    (x120)

That is 2560 x 1600 x 30 x 120 = 14745600000 bits per second.

14.7Gbit/sec is less than the max the interface is capable off.
```

Now for 4096 × 2160 x 30 @ 60Hz
4096 × 2160 x 30 x 60 =  15925248000. Thus the answer is 15.9Gbit/sec